# Symfony2 error on command line

Tags: symfony

When i try to update with composer, or clear cache, or other command i have :

```
    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                     
      Warning: file_put_contents(/vagrant/crm_neo/app/cache/dev/assetic/routing.yml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vagrant/crm_neo/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RouterResourcePass.php line 43


Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

What can i do ? Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure how you got to this point, but you could try creating an empty `/vagrant/crm_neo/app/cache/dev/assetic/routing.yml`

Comment: I have this erro when i create a symfony project for the first time

Comment: Did you go through the interactive setup? If not, try running `composer install` instead of `composer update`

Comment: delete the app/cache/dev folder, and retry